# Deceased people appearing on 2002 UK electoral register?

Tags: england, death-records, 21st-century, voter-lists

I have found someone of interest listed on the 2002 UK electoral register.  I have also found a death certificate for a person with the same name living at the same location who died the previous year. This is not a common name.

Are electoral registers regularly and properly purged of deceased people? Is it likely this is the same person?

Answer (score 3):

I have discovered a deceased person in a modern electoral before. Errors happen, and in your case if you think other evidence points to it being the same person, it is probably the same person.

According to [The completeness and accuracy of electoral registers in Great Britain (March 2010)](http://www.electoralcommission.org.uk/__data/assets/pdf_file/0018/87111/The-completeness-and-accuracy-of-electoral-registers-in-Great-Britain.pdf), the number of deceased individuals in electoral registers is (in 2010) negligible. Among the data given for several localities, the only place with a non-zero percentage of deceased electors was Derby with 0.2% of the electors on the register actually being deceased (see p 78).

On page 110 of the same document:

> Since Electoral Registration Officers (EROs) update the registers each
>   month using updates of recorded deaths from the local registrar,
>   redundant entries relating to deceased voters are minimal. As a
>   result, the cause of the great majority of redundant entries will be a
>   combination of:
>
> - those electors who have moved out of or within the local authority after the annual canvass but have not notified the relevent ERO that
>     they have done so
> - those electors who have moved since the last annual canvass, and whom an ERO opts to 'carry forward' from the previous register in the
>     absence of a response to the annual canvas.

As more and more systems have become computerized, I think the number of these types of errors has probably decreased. In 2002, it's possible that there were more errors of this kind made than in the 2010 report. When a person dies in England today, numerous agencies are notified with a single click.

More information about electoral registration can be found on [The Electoral Commission website](http://www.electoralcommission.org.uk/our-work/our-research/electoral-registration-research).

Answer (score 1):

Bear in mind that there is a legally-defined cut-off date for the Registers, which is, last I heard, 15th October. So anyone who dies after that date actually must appear in the register for "next" year. The register has an effective date of 1 December (again, last I heard), so has to be "published" before then.

We get asked yearly if we still exist (as it were) but I think that is some months before the end of the year. The yearly check should (fraud aside) pick up deceased and otherwise departed people.